# Where is the "vue entry point"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to get bootstrap-vue installed in my vue-cli project. 
I read here https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs :

```
Then, register BootstrapVue in your app entry point:

import Vue from 'vue'
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'

// Install BootstrapVue
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
// Optionally install the BootstrapVue icon components plugin
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
And import Bootstrap and BootstrapVue css files:

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
Alternatively you can import Bootstrap and BootstrapVue scss files in a custom SCSS file:

@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
Make sure to import the custom.scss file in your app entry point:

import './custom.scss'
Be sure to @import or define your custom variable values before including Bootstrap SCSS (bootstrap.scss), and include BootstrapVue SCSS (bootstrap-vue.scss) after that to ensure variables are set up correctly.

Place all of the SCSS @imports into a single SCSS file, and import that single file into your project. Importing individual SCSS files into your project will not share variable values and functions between files by default.

Webpack and Parcel support prepending the scss modules with tilde paths (~) when importing from a scss file:

// Webpack example
@import '~bootstrap';
@import '~bootstrap-vue';
// Parcel example
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import '~bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
For more details how to configure asset loading and how modules are resolved, please consult the module bundlers documentation.
```

Well, where do I need to put all this? xD Im really new to vue.js. Is the main.js the entry point?
And if so, do I need to put all this there? 
This is what my main.js looks like:

```
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Routes from './routes'
import App from './App.vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import './style/customColor.scss';
//import 'regenerator-runtime';

import store from "./store/store";
import { USER_ROLECHECK } from './store/actions/user'
import { REQ_ADMIN_ROLE } from "./utility/namespaces";
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'

Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.config.devtools = true; //this line should be removed in the actual live build!

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: Routes,
    mode: 'history'
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.meta.reqAuth){
    if(store.getters.isAuthenticated){
      if(to.meta.reqAdmin){
        store.dispatch(USER_ROLECHECK, REQ_ADMIN_ROLE).then(() =>{
          next();
        }).catch(() =>{
          next({path: '/'})
        })
      }else{
        next();
      }
    }else{
      next({path: '/login'});
    }
  }else{
    next();
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
   router,
   store,
  render: h => h(App),
})
```

How do I need to update this, what must it look like for the integration to worK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in a `vue-cli` app, the `main.js` file is your apps `entry point`.

What you need to place in your `main.js` is the following:

```js
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'

// Install BootstrapVue
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
// Optionally install the BootstrapVue icon components plugin
// Only needed if you want to use the bootstrap icons. Be aware these are currently in alpha
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)


// Import Bootstrap and Bootstrap-Vue css
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
```

If you want to use `SCSS` you will need to create a new `styles.scss` (the name doesn't matter) file, place these two lines in it

```
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
```

and then import `styles.scss` in your `main.js` instead of the `css` files:

```js
// Replace these
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

// With this
import './path/to/your/styles.scss'
```